# I want to automate android OS and how I can recognize Android application components like buttons?

Tags: android, shell, automation

I want to write an android application that press buttons on other android application , i don't want to use shell scripting like python ! Is there any way to program android similar to C# win32 API ?

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**

Depends. Yes if both apps are yours and are prepared, try [Spoon](http://square.github.io/spoon/), No in other case.

**Long Answer**

Android applications runs in separate processes and every process has not an easy communication with another process. To do so you have to make some kind of pipeline between the two applications called IPC (Inter-process communication) or send a Broadcast Intent. Anyway it will only work if both applications are prepared to do so.

Imagine what can happen' if, for example, I decide to create an application that sends whatsapp's to all your contacts, because I can access the whatsapp application. It is security, every application runs in their own sandbox and you have no way to manipulate one application from another unless the other application is prepared to do it.

Comment: Basically , i have one "black box" android application and i want sort of background process that will start the "black box" app , press buttons on it and then shut it down , i want to know is there any other approaches except  python shell scripting ?

Comment: I don't really think you can do it with python. Android is not a full shell in which you can install what you want, the only way to act in a device is vía adb which has some limited tools. Well you can make your device to be rooted and make changes on the linux inside, but I think it is not a good approach because it won't work on any not rooted device.

Comment: i need to test the "black box" application , i use adb and i want to try nose framework , what do you think about it? Can you suggest something else ?

Comment: Sure, but not in python, I am not sure that this will work. But there is a hole framework yet done for what you are asking, it is Spoon: http://square.github.io/spoon/. I have used it and works fine. Basically your computer acts like a server and your phone as a client that, via some TestCase you program on the app, it sends the info of passed tests and errors to your computer. All orchested via a gradle plugin. Have a look and let me know if this suits your needs

Comment: tnx , very interesting , can i make any other output than HTML

Comment: Not sure, but if you consider the output does not suit your needs you always can custom the library, it is Open Source, and Square people have really good coding skills, it is easy to follow.

Comment: tnx very much , i will research a little bit about it and i will tell you about my progress , i really appreciate your help - tnx again

Comment: Upvote if you found it helpfull. Thnx

Comment: i want to ask you if you worked with APPIUM framework ??

Comment: Nope, I have never used it, but looks fine for what you want